# Ubuntu 18.04 not shutting down or rebooting on MSI laptop

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, msi

I've got MSI gp62m 7rex leopard pro laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 installed on it, running Cinnamon 3.6.7 with GDM3 3.28.0. It's not shutting down, this appears in the logs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ae9Q.jpg

I guess it's not because of the KVM, i tried unloading it with `rmmod` before shutting down, then it freezes on 'Detaching DM devices'.

Graphic drivers are nvidia 390.48, my FS structre:

```
sda                                 119,2G                               
├─sda1                  vfat          512M /boot/efi                     
├─sda2                  ext4          732M /boot                         
└─sda3                  crypto_LUKS   118G                               
  └─sda3_crypt          LVM2_member   118G                               
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   ext4          117G /                             
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap          976M [SWAP]                        
sdb                                 931,5G                               
└─sdb1                  crypto_LUKS 931,5G                               
  └─home_drive          ext4        931,5G /home
```

I also tried removing 'quiet splash' from the /etc/default/grub, didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

For me it came from nvidia drivers. I had to put acpi=off in grub options and remove all nvidia driver related installation. For some reason i got problems with a similar laptop (high end msi and asus, with gtx 1050 for both) on ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, but on 17.10 it works just fine out of the box.

Hope it helps and maybe give you a backup solution

Answer (score -1):

I found this link very useful and it worked!! My MSI gaming laptop was not rebooting for many times. I tried changing many parameters in quiet splash. Nothing worked.. Finally the below link came to my rescue. 
https://gist.github.com/mari-linhares/cef4cb3440408e44963d1447a7db5ae0Installing Ubuntu 18.04

> #### Get Image
>
> https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0
>
> #### Install (solving issues)
>
> - Secure Boot disabled (change this in BIOS, for MSI computers reboot system and press delete a couple of times before the OS is loaded).
> - Possible problem: Screen freezing while installing
>
>   - Reboot system
>   - Go to the Install Ubuntu option (BUT DONT PRESS ENTER)
>   - Press e
>   - Find the line that starts with linux then add modprobe.blacklist=nouveau after quiet splash.
> - Choose a Wifi Network and install third-party software and updates.
> - Once the installation is done, remove the flash drive and reboot.
>
> #### Installing Nvidia Drivers
>
> - Select Ubuntu at GRUB (you may need to repeat the `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` step if the screen freezes again).
> - Make sure Secure Boot is disabled.
> - Access command line (Ctrl+Alt+ F1,F2,F3...F??)
>
>   ```
>   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa  
>   sudo apt update  
>   sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396  
>   sudo reboot
>   ```
>
> #### Installing Conda
>
> - https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux
>
> #### Installing CUDA 9.0 and CUDNN 7.0
>
> - https://medium.com/@taylordenouden/installing-tensorflow-gpu-on-ubuntu-18-04-89a142325138
>
> #### Installing Pytorch 0.4
>
> **create conda env**
>
> ```
> conda create -n torch python=3.6
> install torch (cuda 9)
> conda install -y pytorch=0.4 torchvision cuda90 -c pytorch
> ```
>
> **If CUDA 9 fails, install this way using CUDA 8**
>
> ```
> conda install -y pytorch=0.4 torchvision -c pytorch conda install cuda80 -c soumith
> ```
>
> **test GPU install**
>
> ```
> python -c 'import torch; print(torch.rand(2,3).cuda())'
> ```
>
> #### Installing TensorFlow (1.8)
>
> https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#installing_with_anaconda
>
> REMEMBER
>
> ```
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
> ```
>
> **test GPU install**
>
> ```
> python -c 'from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib; device_lib.list_local_devices()'
> ```
>
> **output:**
>
> ```
> 2018-06-11 11:32:18.954198: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with ...)
> ```